# How to squezee from the bottom $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left (\frac{1}{2^n} \right )-\left (\frac{1}{3^n} \right )}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left (\frac{1}{2^n} \right )-\left (\frac{1}{3^n} \right )}$$
The sequence above can easily be squeezed from the top by sequence devoid of subtraction:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left (\frac{1}{2^n} \right )}=\frac{1}{2}$$
But I can't think of of sequence with smaller terms that involves only $\frac{1}{2^n}$ terms bar from $\sqrt[n]{\left (\frac{1}{2^n} \right )-\left (\frac{1}{2^n} \right )}$ which is not that helpful.

Comment: We have $\sqrt[n]{2^{-n}-3^{-n}}=(1/2)\sqrt[n]{1-(2/3)^n}$, then use the squeezing $1-(2/3)^n\leq \sqrt[n]{1-(2/3)^n} \leq1$.